# Expose API with Basic Authentication in WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 - Dynamic Authentication

Tags: wso2, basic-authentication, wso2-api-manager

There is a WSO2 EI backend running with `Basic Auth` mechanism.

**Postman - WSO2 EI URL Hit:**

[image: WSO2 EI Backend]

- Hosted this backend url in WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 with Basic Auth mechanism rather than `OAuth`
- But this dynamic basic auth is not working, getting   `401 unauthorized ERROR` as per below postman hit.

**Postman - APIM URL Hit:**

[image: wso2 apim hit]

**WSO2 APIM Publisher:**

[image: Publisher]

**WSO2 APIM Dev Portal:**

[image: subscription]

**TryitTool in DEV Portal:**

[image: TryOutTool]

**Scenario:**

[image: Real scenario]

- As per above diagram, Client will send Request to WSO2 APIM Url with Basic Auth credentials which needs to be forwarded to backend url instead of setting static value in `Endpoint Security Configurations` of Publisher portal.

Note: Basic Auth credentials (`admin:admin`) is passed in each api hit

[Reference link](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-basic-authentication/)

Am I missing anything? How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API Gateway drops the authentication header and that’s why you get 401. You can set the EI credentials at the endpoint credentials so that authentication header is passed to the backend. Go to the endpoint section at the APIM and provide the same credentials as the endpoint credentials.

Although your EI endpoint is secured with basic authentication, you don’t need to expose the API at the gateway with basic authentication. You can use OAuth or API keys.

Comment: Hi @Pubci
Thanks for your response, we're in situation where some clients reluctance to move from BasicAuth to OAuth2 for some legacy API's as changes are required from their end, So for such clients need to expose API with the same existing Basic Auth. That's why trying this. As you suggested i set static credentials and working fine. is there any mechanism to make this as dynamic in which client passing credentials need to be sent to backend endpoint? please clarify on the same

Comment: You can try the methods explained in here- https://athiththan11.medium.com/preserve-authorization-header-in-wso2-api-manager-e9469e43d1c0